# How should I approach the creation of bookmarked/saved posts in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Post`, and an `User` model

I want to enable users to save or bookmark posts. In other words, they will click a button and the post will be bookmarked/saved. Then the user will be able to see all those posts listed in a page (like *YouTube's* watch later).

I think I have to create a `Bookmark` model. But I'm not sure what kind of assosiation the models should have with `Post` and `User`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have bookmarks but no other information associated with the bookmark like 'bookmarked comment' or 'blah blah' you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. There you won't need to create a bookmark model. You only need to create the join table in this case. The `has_many :through` is useful in a case when you need to store more information with the relationship. You can go through this [has_and_belongs_to_many_association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

And in user and post models:

```
has_many :bookmarks
```

Also, for more convenience you can use "has_many through" association in your user and post models.

Comment: So the `bookmarks` table in the database only needs an `user_id` and `post_id`? column. What's the name of this kind of association?

Comment: Will this be a `join table` in the database or a join model??

Comment: Yes, only user_id and post_id (or something else what you want :)). This is has_many association. But if we observe relation between user and post through bookmarks - this is many-to-many association.